# office files are being read as zip archive and vice versa. How can I resolve this?

Tags: kde, zip, manjaro, libreoffice, wps-office

I am running Manjaro linux KDE and am enjoying. But opening office & zip file is a pita for me. 
Look the screenshot. My zip file opens by libreoffice (or WPS). And if I correct it in file properties to point it to open by ark, then office files start opening by ark. The file type seem to get added automatically. I can never open any zip or office file without right click.

Weird problem. I wonder if I am the only one too suffer from it. Though, no other filetypes are in conflict like this except zip and office files.
I couldn't find any settings/options to correct it. Duckduckgoing also doesn't give any post.
Any help input would be well appreciated. Thanks.[image: office-zip filetype conflict]

Comment: check here ? https://forum.manjaro.org/t/xlsx-and-docx-files-are-opened-as-zip-file/25814

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have changed according to a helpful advice in the page, and lets see if the solution persists.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an easy and straightforward solution [on the Manjaro's Community forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/xlsx-and-docx-files-are-opened-as-zip-file/25814).

In my case WPS Office seems to have broken some MIME format assigns on my system.

These are the steps you have you follow:

1. Remove the xml WPS-related files from `/usr/share/mime/packages/` (wps-office-et.xml wps-office-wpp.xml wps-office-wps.xml and wps-office-pdf)
2. Then `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`
3. It should now work (close and open your file explorer if it doesn't). Otherwise you can directly assign which app should open the format in the window shown on the screenshot above.

Answer (score -1):

Similar issue with .xlsm files and their ilk.  It seems a priority issue with zip files, declared for mime-info in /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml.

Saved a backup copy, then edited /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml, and commented out, `<!-- Commented out b/c... -->` , the mime definition for zip files `<mime-type type="application/zip">[...]</mine-type>`. 
Then $> sudo update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime/

This workaround seems to hold, until creating ".zip" files with KDE/Dolpin - Ark, which then fails with odd permission error.

So adding the magic priority to *.xlsm definition in "freedesktop.org.xml" file, does fix both the above, but feels not in-line with how the mime db should work (but good enough for now ;) )

So for the ".xlsm" type files,
edit /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml, and replace:

```
<glob pattern="*.xlsm"/>
```

with:

```
<magic priority="50">
    <match value="PK\003\004" type="string" offset="0"/>
</magic>
<glob pattern="*.xlsm"/>
```

Then, run:

```
$> sudo update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime/
```

And this will most likely work for "*.pptx", etc.
And you should be able to remove the custom/user mods to the "application/zip" mime.